# Remove "blog" in .htaccess 301 redirect (old blogpost > new blogpost)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I migrate blog posts from **Yola CMS** to **Wordpress** and I don't know how to remove "blog" from old path alias (slug) and redirect the page using 301 to the new URL:

This is the scenario:

```
http://www.example.net/blog/this-is-path-alias-slug > http://www.example.com/this-is-path-alias-slug/
```

Please, note that:

- 1th alias has `net` domain and 2nd has `com` domain
- 2nd alias has slash `/` at the end

Answer (score 2):

There are several Plugins for WordPress to manage custom redirects. I will not recommend a specific tool, but most of those will do the job. Install one of these Plugins and enter the redirection URLs accordingly.

Examples:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: Redirection is a way to go.